# Window properties - how are they implemented?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-mobile, win64

I'm curious if there is anyone around here that has inside information on the implementation details of window properties (`SetProp`, `GetProp`, etc.) in Windows.

[SetProp @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633568(VS.85).aspx)
[GetProp @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633564(VS.85).aspx)

For instance, how are storage and lookups done?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa922089.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa928286.aspx for the Windows Mobile links. don't know if there is a difference in the docs.

Comment: @ctacke: there seems to be docs at MSDN showing the functionality is available in Windows Mobile.

Comment: @Shaihi: I've rolled back.  I don't have time to test to see if they actually work, but for some reason I seem to recall they don't.

Comment: @ctacke: Sure they work on WinCE/Mo. And I've always wondered how they'd measure up against Set/GetWindowLong with extra window data. On WinCE/Mo, I mean.

Comment: yep, I see that now. It's defined in kthunks.lib, which we don't have public source for, so the implementation is opaque. Agreed that it would be interesting to see how they perform, but it sure looks like you get a kernel context switch (in 6.0 anyway) when you use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warning: I looked at this a *long* time ago, so 1) my memory may be wrong, and 2) it may be out of date, even if I am remembering correctly.

When I looked, I'm pretty sure they were implemented as linked-lists, and performance was *quite* poor if you had more than a few properties for a window.

Comment: I second that, its a linked list located in the window object. To find the property, the list needs to be traversed. And you even need a context switch in kernel mode. I wont recommend that.
Source: Reactos (http://reactos-mirror.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/reactos/subsystems/win32/win32k/ntuser/prop.c) & Own work

Comment: @evilpie: Interesting source, but my tag list didn't include `reactos`...  ;-)